# How to fix 'Key already exists Parameter name: Key' error in UltraGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I wanted to setting Grid Column to coded Grid InitializeLayout Event at the beginning of coding.

```
UltraGridColumn ugc = null;

ugc = e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns.Add(key,caption);

ugc = e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns.Add(key2, caption2);
ugc.CellAppearance.TextHAlign = HAlign.Left;
ugc.Width = 190;
ugc.LockedWidth = true;
```

And every time you search, I tried to bind to Grid DataSource by receiving a value from the DB as DataTable.

```
uGrid.DataSource = dt;
```

This code caused an error.

> Key already exists Parameter name: Key

I don't know what's causing this error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the InitializeLayout event check if the column exists before adding. That way it prevents duplicating.
//something like this 
`if(!e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns.Exists("key"))
       e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns.Add(key,caption);`